# Почему элементы в массиве не изменяются?

Tags: ruby

Есть задачка, которую я в теории решил, однако не изменяется значение в массиве temp. В чем загвоздка?

```
=begin 
Заполнить квадратную матрицу размера n на n натуральными
числами от 1 до n**2 в указанном порядке:

        | 1 2 3 |
        | 6 5 4 |
        | 7 8 9 |
=end


glob_arr = []
temp = []

puts "Введите n"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
for i in 1..n
  temp<<i
end

for i in 0..n-1
  if i%2==0
      glob_arr << temp
  else
      glob_arr << temp.reverse
  end
  temp.reverse.each{ |e| e+=1 }
end
glob_arr.each { |e| puts e.to_s }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
glob_arr = []

puts "Введите n"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
temp = Array.new(n, 0).fill { |i| i + 1 }

n.times do |i|
  if i.even?
      glob_arr << temp.dup
  else
      glob_arr << temp.reverse
  end
  glob_arr[i].map!{ |e| e += n * i }
end

glob_arr.each { |e| puts e.to_s }
```

В результате получается следующий вывод

```
Введите n
3
[1, 2, 3]
[6, 5, 4]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Загвоздка в том, что вы элементам массива `glob_arr` присваиваете один и тот же массив `temp`. В ruby все является объектом, а объекты передаются по ссылкам. В результате меняя потом одну строку матрицы, вы затронете все три строки. Поэтому лучше `temp` клонировать, например, при помощи метода `dup` - тогда строки матрицы будут разными массивами, которые можно будет преобразовывать независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Вновь вы выручили. У меня были мысли по этому поводу. Но про `dup` не слышал. Надо теорию бы подтянуть. 
Мне стало как то неудобно.

Comment: @QWD666 Не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте, что знаем расскажем, чем сможем - поможем :)

Comment: @cheops я правильно понимаю, что вместо этой сточки `glob_arr << temp.dup.reverse` можно записать `glob_arr << temp.reverse`, и ничего не поменяется?

Comment: @jisecayeyo да, совершенно, верно, в этой строчке dup лишний, так как reverse сам создает копию массива. Спасибо за замечание, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Ну и магия

```
n=9
result=(1..n).to_a.each_slice(Math.sqrt(n)).each_with_index.map { |x, i| (i.even?) ? x : x.reverse }
p result
```

выдаст

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Правда задача гласит "1 до n**2", но автор берет n как конечное число, а не возводит в квадрат, поэтому для вычисления размера массива берем корень.

Comment: А хотите ещё интенсивнее магию? Её есть у меня! `(1..9).each_slice(3).map.with_index { |x, i| i.even? ? x : x.reverse }`

Comment: @D-side на том же tryruby.org "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each_slice' for 1..9:Range>". map.with_index  у меня чет не так заработало изначально и не стал мудриь просто развернул.

Comment: Там старый, небось. Я гонял на 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения значений массива нужно использвать функцию `map`. Функция возвратит новый массив с изменениями, не затронув данные в исходном массиве. Чтобы заменить данные в исходном массиве, нужно использовать функцию `map!`.
В вашем случае `temp.reverse!.map!{ |e| e+=1 }`, или `temp.map!{ |e| e+=1 }`reverse!.
Восклицательный знак в конце методов в Ruby означает, что изменение коснется исходных данных.
Если мы выполним `temp.reverse.map!{ |e| e+=1 }`, то метод `reverse` возвратит новый массив с измененными данными и метод `map!` будет вызван уже для нового массива, поэтому изменений вы не заметите.
Описанное выше поможет только изменить значение массива, но для првильного решения задачи смотрите ответ @cheops.

Comment: пробовал и через мап, однако в этом и есть проблема он или изменяет все данные на одинаковые, или работает так же как и у меня в примере.

Comment: @QWD666, Вы использовали `map!` (именно с восклицательным знаком)?

Comment: Да. А так же и без него.

Comment: @QWD666, проблема в методе `reverse`. Сделайте сначала `temp.map!{ |e| e+=1 }`, а затем `temp.reverse!`. Или же `temp.map!{ |e| e+=1 }.reverse!`